# unable to connect to sql server ce database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-ce

I am trying to open a `SqlConnection` for a CE (.sdf) database but it throws an exception:

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

What I did is to right-click the App_Data folder and create a database there. Then I copied the connection string from its properties and placed it in web.config. When I try to "Test the connection" it succeeds.

Other than the connection string, I did not specify other attributes like the data source, provider name, etc.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to a SQL Server Compact database file, you must use the **SqlCeConnection** class, not SqlConnection. Add a reference to the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll ADO.NET provider DLL file to use the SqlCeConnection class